# How can i get a random response ping?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so, im pretty new to coding, and im trying to make a discord bot command that gives a random response, like "{person who wrote message} threw a potato at everyone." if you ping someone in your message it would say something like "{person who wrote the message} threw a potato at {person who was pinged}." im having trouble with the second part. heres my code:

````
        let randomNbr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        message.reply(throws[randomNbr]);
        var user = message.mentions.users.first();
        if ('?throw <@${user.id}>') return message.reply
        message.reply[" threw a potato at <@${user.id}>! how dare!"," threw apples at <@${user.id}>! heheheh."] ```
````

Comment: What language is `<@${user.id}>`? What do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, something like this could be very easily done with the nullish coalescing operator (Or the ternary operator, short circuit evaluation, etc. - I'll focus on nullish coalescing as I see it the most efficient in this case). We could very simply create an array of strings with the random messages we're looking to find, and add the nullish coalescing operator in order to figure out whether a person was mentioned or not. See an example of one of those strings below.

```js
message.channel.send(`${message.author} threw a potato at ${message.mentions.users.first() ?? "everyone"}!`);
```